# Is there an API in Windows 7 for creating "split menu items"?

Tags: user-interface, windows-7, windows-vista, menuitem

I don't know what their official name is, but I mean these things:

[image: Split menu item]

Is there an official API for creating those in my own program?

And related question: Did you ever see these "split menu items" used anywhere other than the start menu? Where? This could point at an API.

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at my own start menu, I'm guessing that most are generated the same way "Recent Documents" used to be done. i.e., observing the files that programs open.

As for new APIs, this page might be a good place to start sniffing around: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461765%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To create tasks like internet explorer etc, use [ICustomDestinationList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)->AddUserTasks(), the recent items should show up for file types you are registered to handle (They are added by the open/save dialog or manually by calling SHAddToRecentDocs())

Comment: I meant creating a general "split menu item", not necessarily tasks to an app. For example if I show a context menu in my program, I want to have one of those in that menu.